# Removing Duplicates in SQL without using Distinct function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm probably missing something simple on this

```
SELECT distinct
A.ClaimNumber, 
C.ActivityDetail, 
C.CreatedDateTime AS DateClosed, 
A.CreatedDate as OpenDate, 
DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(DATE,A.CreatedDate),CONVERT(DATE,C.CreatedDateTime)) AS 'Days until closed'
FROM
    ASR.dbo.tblRepairRequestActivityStream C
    JOIN ASR.dbo.tblClaimReason A
    ON  
        A.ClaimNumber = C.ClaimNumber

WHERE
    C.ActivityDetail = 'FROM Ready_For_Pickup TO Closed'
    AND C.CreatedDateTime > '2017-04-16'
    and a.Item not like 'emms'
    and a.Item not like 'detl' 
    and a.item not like 'wind'
GROUP BY
    A.ClaimNumber, C.ActivityDetail, C.CreatedDateTime, A.CreatedDate, a.Item
ORDER BY 
    C.CreatedDateTime
```

I'm still getting duplicates on the claim numbers and i believe it could be that the ticket gets reopen and closed again. How can i remove the duplicates ?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please don't tag unrelated products.

Comment: Not related to your problem. But you could simplify those `LIKE` with `a.Item NOT IN ('emms', 'detl' , 'wind')` ... `LIKE` without `%` is just an equal `=` comparasion

Comment: I assume the entire record isn't duplicates though. Which field is different amongst your duplicates? Which value of those different values is the "Correct" one that you want to display and why? Based on that you can determine how to display that particular value.

Comment: Why do you have `a.Item` in the `Group By` when it's not in the `Select` statement?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion on the a.item. I was using that to find more information on the tickets but i was getting multiple duplicates in that piece as well. By eliminating it in my select query it removed about 200 duplicates from that and i forgot to remove it from my group by statement.

Comment: Since you've accepted an answer based on proprietary Transact-SQL features, I've assumed this question has nothing to do with MySQL and removed the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `min()` and/or `max()` for your dates like so:

```
select
    A.ClaimNumber
  , C.ActivityDetail
  , max(C.CreatedDateTime) as DateClosed
  , min(A.CreatedDate) as OpenDate
  , datediff(day, convert(date,min(A.CreatedDate)), convert(date, max(C.CreatedDateTime)) as [Days until closed]
from asr.dbo.tblRepairRequestActivityStream C
  inner join asr.dbo.tblClaimReason A 
    on A.ClaimNumber = C.ClaimNumber
where C.ActivityDetail = 'from Ready_For_Pickup to Closed' 
  and C.CreatedDateTime > '2017-04-16'
  and a.Item not like 'emms' 
  and a.Item not like 'detl' 
  and a.item not like 'wind'
group by 
    A.ClaimNumber
  , C.ActivityDetail
  --, C.CreatedDateTime
  --, A.CreatedDate
  --, a.Item /* not in select */
order by max(C.CreatedDateTime)
```

Also, `a.Item` is in your `group by` but not in your `select`, which may have been causing additional duplicates.

---

**[`top with ties`](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** using **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** version:

```
select top 1 with ties
    A.ClaimNumber
  , C.ActivityDetail
  , C.CreatedDateTime as DateClosed
  , A.CreatedDate as OpenDate
  , datediff(day, convert(date,A.CreatedDate), convert(date, C.CreatedDateTime)) as [Days until closed]
from asr.dbo.tblRepairRequestActivityStream C
  inner join asr.dbo.tblClaimReason A 
    on A.ClaimNumber = C.ClaimNumber
where C.ActivityDetail = 'from Ready_For_Pickup to Closed' 
  and C.CreatedDateTime > '2017-04-16'
  and a.Item not in ('emms','detl','wind')
order by row_number() over (
  partition by A.ClaimNumber 
  order by c.CreatedDatetime desc /* most recent */
         , a.CreatedDate desc     /* most recent */
  )
```

Using a [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** version:

```
;with cte as (
  select
      A.ClaimNumber
    , C.ActivityDetail
    , C.CreatedDateTime as DateClosed
    , A.CreatedDate as OpenDate
    , datediff(day, convert(date,A.CreatedDate), convert(date, C.CreatedDateTime)) as [Days until closed]
    , rn = row_number() over (
      partition by A.ClaimNumber 
      order by c.CreatedDatetime desc /* most recent */
             , a.CreatedDate desc     /* most recent */
      )
  from asr.dbo.tblRepairRequestActivityStream C
    inner join asr.dbo.tblClaimReason A 
      on A.ClaimNumber = C.ClaimNumber
  where C.ActivityDetail = 'from Ready_For_Pickup to Closed' 
    and C.CreatedDateTime > '2017-04-16'
    and a.Item not in ('emms','detl','wind')
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!